# Why does NSFileProtectionComplete not work?

Tags: ios, encryption

I'd like to protect my apps data using `NSFileProtectionComplete`. To do so I've used an entitlements plist like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>DataProtectionClass</key>
        <string>NSFileProtectionComplete</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However when I plug my device in to my mac and open it with a tool such as iExplorer I can read all my files within my apps document folder without me having to unlock my phone. I have data protection enabled and have a pin set to unlock the device.

Why is the encryption not working and how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding data protection to a property list doesn't work unless the capability is enabled in your application properties.

[image]